# Getting the name of the container from within the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cluster-computing

I would like to get the docker container name from within a container. I need this information because I am running a script from the Dockerfile as an `ENTRYPOINT` that needs to know the node number. I am using the `--scale` with `docker-compose` to create a cluster of my image.
I am able to get the `hostname` of the container which is the container ID. But is there a way to get the container name from inside the container?

Comment: It would be better to pass the node number as an argument.

Comment: how would you do pass the node number from Dockerfile?

Comment: The Dockerfile creates an image and an image can spawn many containers. You wouldn't put it in the Dockerfile, you'd add it to the end of `docker run` or put it in `docker-compose.yml` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker [remote apis](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/) should work for you.

Depending on the version of your docker used appropriate version of remote api. Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/#api-version-matrix) for more info.

I made use of [container-inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/ContainerInspect) api to retrieve the `container name`.

Follow these steps:

- Figure out on which `port` docker daemon is listening. In my case it was `2375` which is the default port.

```
$ netstat -anp | grep dockerd
tcp        0      0 :::2375                 :::*                    LISTEN      7/dockerd
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.18.0.110:2375 ::ffff:172.18.0.1:29445 ESTABLISHED 7/dockerd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1242188041 7/dockerd           /var/run/docker/metrics.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1242187193 7/dockerd           /var/run/docker.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1242186375 7/dockerd           /var/run/docker/libnetwork/79ba9bb412445c757dd4cc2fc30c1cbc7efde8482bdc4c1cf15c4ce0e4190752.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1242187211 7/dockerd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1242183625 7/dockerd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1242184185 7/dockerd
```

- Run a container and retrieve the container name.

```
$ docker run -it alpine sh
/ # apk update
/ # apk add curl
/ # apk add jq
/ # curl -s 192.168.0.37:2375/containers/$HOSTNAME/json | jq -r ".Name"
/zen_wescoff
```

**NOTE:** Here 192.168.0.37 is the ip of my machine. Also apart from `container name` you can retrieve lot of information using these docker remote apis.

Sample full output of container-inspect api

```
/ # curl -s 192.168.0.37:2375/containers/$HOSTNAME/json?pretty=true
{
    "Id": "3409974f45bedacd3adbe663679e4eb7a74006483e3a3b04985e5a7cc65229b9",
    "Created": "2019-06-20T09:09:51.258807808Z",
    "Path": "sh",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 3824,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2019-06-20T09:09:53.341188978Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:4d90542f0623c71f1f9c11be3da23167174ac9d93731cf91912922e916bab02c",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/3409974f45bedacd3adbe663679e4eb7a74006483e3a3b04985e5a7cc65229b9/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/3409974f45bedacd3adbe663679e4eb7a74006483e3a3b04985e5a7cc65229b9/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/3409974f45bedacd3adbe663679e4eb7a74006483e3a3b04985e5a7cc65229b9/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/3409974f45bedacd3adbe663679e4eb7a74006483e3a3b04985e5a7cc65229b9/3409974f45bedacd3adbe663679e4eb7a74006483e3a3b04985e5a7cc65229b9-json.log",
    "Name": "/jovial_moser",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {},
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Capabilities": null,
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [0, 0],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "DiskQuota": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": ["/proc/asound", "/proc/acpi", "/proc/kcore", "/proc/keys", "/proc/latency_stats", "/proc/timer_list", "/proc/timer_stats", "/proc/sched_debug", "/proc/scsi", "/sys/firmware"],
        "ReadonlyPaths": ["/proc/bus", "/proc/fs", "/proc/irq", "/proc/sys", "/proc/sysrq-trigger"]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a5f16849169cb7c773f4d204089f8e53daf5b648864846ee1d1f076cef9f8a39-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/edb63c15d70f0a29c60f3725ed952dd76439bef4da8915e66ffe6ed1ecf02107/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a5f16849169cb7c773f4d204089f8e53daf5b648864846ee1d1f076cef9f8a39/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a5f16849169cb7c773f4d204089f8e53daf5b648864846ee1d1f076cef9f8a39/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a5f16849169cb7c773f4d204089f8e53daf5b648864846ee1d1f076cef9f8a39/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "3409974f45be",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": true,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "StdinOnce": true,
        "Env": ["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"],
        "Cmd": ["sh"],
        "Image": "alpine",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "7f41a5043e99bb110e215ac8e13a8a2c37838b25c6a9fa985584ff458c1e52cc",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {},
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7f41a5043e99",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "7aa9f269772edff8a9b7f895d51d6dd472a5820ff56a643134465ab8bff1914e",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "55987078c24843c830172de5c352b00c96cb3f177a349437dd7bee9bd1814e86",
                "EndpointID": "7aa9f269772edff8a9b7f895d51d6dd472a5820ff56a643134465ab8bff1914e",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in-short you need to know `ip` for your machine and the `port` on which docker daemon is listening to retrieve any sort of information from within the container.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Mount the docker socket to your container:

```
 myservice:
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

Then use a lib or directly query the docker api:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/json
```

This will return an array of all the running containers which includes the field:

```
{ Names: ['/proj_myservice_1', '/proj_myservice_2'] }
```

If you've scaled your containers up and are looking to communicate with the sibling containers inside a container, docker automatically detects this if you make requests to: http://myservice{:port} from inside your container. Docker will auto-discover the container and route you to a random container.