# Docker self-upgrade after restart

Tags: docker, containers

I'm looking for a way to pull the latest image in Docker vanilla after a container crashed/exited.

As in my current architecture, I don't have access to Docker Engine API but only to the container itself, I want to be able to update the container based on the image after this service is exited.

The Docker way to upgrade containers seems to be the following:

```
docker pull mysql 
docker stop my-mysql-container 
docker rm my-mysql-container 
docker run --name=my-mysql-container --restart=always \
 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypwd -v /my/data/dir:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql
```

But that's based on the Docker engine CLI API and as I explained before - that's not an approach that I want to try.

Is there a possible way to configure the Docker when the container is pulling again the image from the latest repository upon restart/crash?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2733).

Which [seems](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2733#issuecomment-277171576) possible using `docker service update` for which you will need `docker swarm`. With plain docker installed on single VM, don't seems feasible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: looks like there is no solution for what I'm looking for, I need to run a Docker command from inside the container

Comment: Yes thats not possible. But if you want to run commands from within the docker  container then use docker remote apis. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675083/getting-the-name-of-the-container-from-within-the-container/56682693#56682693 I have answered this earlier.